# ошибка при инсталляции на телефон Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь запустить на телефоне
получаю вот такую ошибку
подскажите как поправить?

```
05/02 21:45:22: Launching 'app' on Google Pixel 2 XL.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 2454754' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:471)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2707)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1106)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:176)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21805)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4876)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4031)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:234)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:150)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:165)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:581)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:469)
... 11 more''
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Включена ли отладка в настройках телефона?
2) Сколько весит приложение?
3) Достаточно ли свободной памяти на телефоне?

Comment: Navigation Drawer Activity пустое приложение пытался запустить,странно то что до этого все работало отлично,Отладка включена, опять же до этого все работало

Comment: Проверьте, достаточно ли свободного места на телефоне

Comment: решилось.видимо проблема была в проводе.хотя это очень странно